# Animate Longpress on UITableViewCell with background Color

Tags: swift

I want to animate my UITableViewCell on Longpress.

When a user starts holding on a cell it should get a light green colour - after holding on the cell the colour should get more intense to a dark green and then fire a event and the `Longpressgesture` is done.

This is my normal Longpress Recognizer

```
// In the viewDidLoad
    var longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToLPGesture:")

    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 2;


func respondToLPGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began) {

    }
}
```

Do I need to set the minimumPressDuration to 0.1 seconds and then add a additional waiting Time? Or how can I handle that in swift? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` works is that after the `minimumPressDuration` is hit, the given selector will be repeatedly fire with different states.

First of all, your method will be fired with the state `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`. This is when you will start colouring your cell.
I would advise at this point to store the time with `CACurrentMediaTime()`.

Your method will then be fired with the state `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`. Here you can check the current `CACurrentMediaTime()` against the one you stored in the beginning, and use the delta to calculate an intensity for the colour of green you would like.

The long press gesture will end with the state if `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` and it is here that you can do you completion handling.

SO:

```
func respondToLongPressGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
{
    switch gesture.state
    {
        case .Began:
            self.beginPressTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
        case .Changed:
            var deltaTime = CACurrentMediaTime() - self.beginPressTime
            var greenColor = self.greenColourForTimeDelta(deltaTime)
            gesture.view.backgroundColor = greenColor
        case .Ended:
            self.gestureDidFinish(gesture)
    }
}
```